# Would you put allowed Origin in a JWT token?

Tags: cors, jwt

Suppose I have an API to protect at somedomain.com. A single page app client wishes to use it, and sets up an authentication endpoint on auth.somedomain.com for their app. The app is served from coolapps.com.

Would you put coolapps.com in a JWT token issued to succesful logins on this apps specific authentication endpoint? Then that token could be restricted to scripts just loaded from coolapp.com, and not any other domain, assuming the browser is not misbehaving.

Would the permitted domain go in the 'aud' field (intended audience) of the JWT token?

===

Note, the aim would be to prevent cross site request forgery. The API has to allow some cross domain requests, so that apps on third party sites can access it. An extra check would be made to ensure that the authentication token matches the domain where the requests are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that becomes really important when auth.somedomain.com provides tokens to more than just coolapps.com. In case there's no audience, administrators/app-developers from one domain could replay their token against another domain to impersonate the enduser.

If you have a more granular application landscape i.e. different applications managed by different administrators on subdomains, or even on the same domain, you may choose to even further restrict the audience by using subdomain or individual application identifiers in the `aud` field.

Comment: What do you mean by "individual application identifiers"? I don't think with an SPA you can have a client secret, because it can't be kept secret. Which is why I think restricting clients by domain is a good use of the 'aud' field.

Comment: fair point, in the SPA use case it would be "API identifiers"; in OAuth the audience is not the client but the protected resource